# Set time out 5 seconds for one by one number in array, but not for all at once

Tags: javascript, loops, settimeout, delay, each

I have array with 100 numbers, i want to add active class to 20 of them, that part is ok and working. But i want delay between every number.

I tried with settimeout, but it only delays for 5 seconds all numbers at once, but i want to set active class one by one with delay of 5 seconds. Please help.

```js
function numbers() { 
                    
                        var activequantities;
                    activequantities = "@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Numbers)".split(",");
// this is array with sorted random numbers 20 of 100 example [22,33,46,57,etc]


                    function setClassNextItem(index)
{
    if (index >= activequantities.lenght) return;

    var value = activequantities[index];
    $(`.grid-container div[data-tabid=${value}]`).addClass('active');
    setTimeout(setClassNextItem(++index), 5000);
}

$(".grid-container div").removeClass('active');
                    setTimeout(setClassNextItem(0), 5000);

                        
                        
                }
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
        <div class="grid-item">

            <div class="grid-container2">
                <div class="grid-item2" data-tabid="1">1</div>
                <div class="grid-item2" data-tabid="2">2</div>
                <div class="grid-item2" data-tabid="3">3</div>
                <div class="grid-item2" data-tabid="4">4</div>
                </div>
```

Add active class one by one. With delay of 5 seconds between each number.

Comment: Are you asking for a delay of 5 seconds between each successive element you added a class to? i.e. first => 5s, second => 10s, ... Nth => (N * 5)s?

Comment: i have updated my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to convert `activequantities` to a numbers array and do something like this:

```
function setClassNextItem(index)
{
    if (index >= activequantities.lenght) return;

    var value = activequantities[index];
    $(`.grid-container div[data-tabid=${value}]`).addClass('active');
    setTimeout(setClassNextItem(++index), 5000);
}

$(".grid-container div").removeClass('active');
setTimeout(setClassNextItem(0), 5000);
```

Comment: Same thing happens, it add active classs instantly to all numbers from array without delay between each number. I created test array and same thing.

Comment: html structure looks like this  <div class="grid-item">

            <div class="grid-container2">
                <div class="grid-item2" data-tabid="1">1</div>
                <div class="grid-item2" data-tabid="2">2</div>
                <div class="grid-item2" data-tabid="3">3</div>

Comment: Do this change `setTimeout(() => setClassNextItem(++index), 5000);`

Comment: Thats it! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Iterate through your filtered elements array and add an `(index + 1) * interval` timeout for the callback to add the classname.

```js
for (i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
  setTimeout(
    function (i) {
      //$this.addClass("active");
      console.log(`Add "active" class to element ${i}`);
    },
    (i + 1) * 1000, // shortened to 1 second for demo
    i
  );
}
```

Comment: Same thing happens. i edited my code from question,i removed loop from my code it is unnecessary. The dev-cc is close to solution.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to stackoverflow! The function `setTimeout` returns an Async Promise that will resolve in x ms. If you run this function in a loop, you simply add more promises to be resolved, but they will all resolve close to the same time. Ex:

Send first Promise : it will wait 5 seconds
One miliseconds later, send another promise that will wait 5 second
...
5 seconds later the first Promise resolve correctly.
1 ms later, the second promise resolve correctly
...

This behaviour makes all of your promises resolve almost at the same time, just 5 seconds after you initialized them.

In your case, since you want to execute a function at a precise interval, you need the `setInterval`. The `setInterval` function also takes a time in MS and a function but it repeat this function every x ms, or until the interval is stopped programmaticaly. EX:

```js
var counting = 0;
var myInterval = setInterval(function() {
    //we do something...
    console.log('loop:' + counting ++);
    if(counting === 10) {
        // we do this 10 times, than we stop the interval
        clearInterval(myInterval);
    }
}, 1000);
```

Here I'm using 1sec interval because 5 is way too long for a demo.

Answer (score 0):

[Drew's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58250226/3120446) is the best and simplest so far.  Another option is to go the `async function`/`promise` route.

```js
/**
 * Time in milliseconds to wait between setting elements to active.
 */
const delayTime = 500, // shortened to half a second for the example
  $app = $('#app');

/**
 * Whether or not the routine is currently running.
 */
let stopped = true;

/**
 * Returns a promise that resolves after the specified number of milliseconds.
 */
function delay(ms) {
  return new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, ms));
}

function setActiveInSerial() {
  // a little user-friendly UI work
  stopped = !stopped;
  if (stopped) {
    $('#btn').text('Run');
  } else {
    $('#btn').text('Stop');
  }

  // promise that lets us serialize asynchronous functions
  let promise = Promise.resolve();

  $app.children().each(function() {
    promise = promise.then(async() => {
      if (stopped) {
        return;
      }

      $(this).addClass('active');

      // wait for `delayTime` to pass before resolving the promise
      await delay(delayTime);
      
      $(this).removeClass('active');
    })
  });
  
  // mark the routine as stopped and reset the button
  promise.then(() => {
    stopped = true;
    $('#btn').text('Run');
  });
}

// populate with items
for (let i = 1; i <= 20; i++) {
  $app.append($('<span>').text(`Item ${i}`));
}

// attach function to run button
$('#btn').click(setActiveInSerial);
```

```css
#app {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#app .active {
  background-color: cyan;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btn">Run</button>
<div id="app"></div>
```

This code is obviously longer, but it's more flexible, and it's good practice for learning promises and async functions.  It has the added benefit of not needing to search through all of the children of your element in order to remove the `active` class.